# Intersection Observer does not trigger on fast scroll

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have a list and on its top and bottom (first/last child) there are sentinels divs. Those are observed by their observers. Infinite in-place scroll logic works nicely up until you scroll too fast.

I think that the scroll is so fast that the sentinel doesn't even appear in the viewport but immediately jumps over.

Is there a way to counteract this ?

Comment: Here is your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951380/intersection-observer-fails-sometimes-when-i-scroll-fast

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that. In the end I ditched the IO and opted for custom way of counting what comes from the backend and should be displayed based on item height and scroll position. Took 2 months though